# How to find a good individualising set in graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

The procedure called **individualization** breaks symmetry arbitrarily. It chooses some nodes in the graph, arbitrarily, to give their own unique names.

Suppose there exists a set $S \subset V$, such that after individualising this set and running plane WL ([Weisfeiler-Lehman](https://davidbieber.com/post/2019-05-10-weisfeiler-lehman-isomorphism-test/)) algorithm each vertex gets a unique label (i.e. discretised ). There may be other subsets of $V$ of the same size as $S$, whose individualisation (after running WL procedure) does not assign an unique label to each vertex of input graph.

I am not individualising $k$ vertices simultaneously, but individualising one and then running the WL procedure.

Is there any way to minimise the individualising set size? If it is given that individualising $l$ many vertices is sufficient?

**Question** : After individualising one vertex of an input graph and then running the WL, I will have some equitable partitions of the vertex set of the input graph $G$. How should the second vertex for individualisation process be chosen? To me it appears I should choose a vertex who has, say, almost the same number of neighbours as non-neighbours. I have tried some other parameters like degree etc to pick the second vertex, but it doesn't seem to work. **The best choice seems, to me, the vertex which belongs to the same orbit as the first vertex.**

Please note that I don't want to try all possible choices of $S$ and that I am looking at this from a **theoretical point** of view completely.

**EDIT:** If the input graph is regular then the choice of the first vertex is not important. I mean to say there is always going to be an individualising set (minimum size) which contain this first vertex. And since the input graph is regular, the number of neighbours and non-neighbours set size will be the same for every choice of first vertex.

Comment: I am guessing that one cannot find the exact minimum-size set without trying all possibilities. It sounds like you are looking for an algorithm to run in practice (rather than worst-case guarantees). In that case, you might try looking at the color-distance partition from each vertex (from a given v, how many vertices have color c and distance d from v?) and choose the vertex for which its color-distance partition has the most parts.

Comment: Maybe, you can use the graph signature, if A is a characteristic matrix of the graph, then P(X)=det(A-XId) is a signature of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of graph. Whatever algorithm you choose there are probably graphs that it works badly on. Similarly, given a vertex choice method, there are graphs it is bad for. Here are two examples:

The first is one where it is unwise to pick a vertex adjacent to half the others. Let $G$ be a strongly regular graph with $n$ vertices of degree $d$ where $d \leq \frac{n}{2}.$  Then make a new bipartite graph also regular of degree $d$ but with twice as many vertices by replacing each vertex $x$ by a pair $x_1,x_2$ and each edge $(x,y)$ by the $2$ edges $(x_1,y_2)$ and $(y_1,x_2)$ Finally, add two new vertices $X_1$ and $X_2$ with $X_1$ adjacent to all the $u_2$ (and also $X_2$) and $X_2$ adjacent to all the $u_1$ (and also $X_1$.) These two new vertices are the only ones adjacent to half the vertices (the rest are adjacent to under a quarter of the vertices.) But picking an $X_i$ as a named vertex at any stage is of little to no use.

To give an example where your second idea does not do well I need to know what you mean by "in the same orbit." Are you saying that the graph (before any vertices get names) has an automorphism group with orbits and the first two points chosen come (one at a time) from the same orbit? I don't like this construction as much as the other one, but replace every vertex $x$ by a $K_m$ with vertices $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m.$  Then replace every edge $(x,y)$ with the $m$ edges $(x_i,y_i).$ If your first chosen vertex is, say, $u_1$ then certainly $u_2$ is in the same orbit but picking it next is not very helpful. I suppose that a distinguishing set must utilize at least $m-1$ of the labels. Now it might be that some $v_2$ is a good thing to pick next but your rule would make picking $v_1$ equally attractive, which it shouldn't be. Since I don't know for sure what your suggestion is, I'll stop there. Except to say that $m$ need not be too large. I do like the idea that there is no $m$-clique in the starting graph. Then it is obvious if an edge is of the type $(x_i,x_j)$ or of type $(x_i,y_i).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Picking $X_i$'s as a named vertices are of use. Because picking say $X_1$, I will be able to differentiate between vertices of one partition from the another. individualising $X_1$, will change the labelings of the vertices in a partition in which $X_1$ has neighbours. Suppose I am not naming any vertex then there are only two types of labels are there in the graph you have mentioned.

Comment: Before you label anything there are $2$ types. If you pick an $X_i$ first you get $4$ types. If you pick a $u_1$ you have at least  $6$ types and maybe more. The question was also about the second choice. Whatever the first choice is, picking an $X_i$ second gives no new information at all.

Comment: Yes definitely, I thought in the first paragraph you were saying about any stage in the process.

Comment: After applying WL algorithm we will get partitions, now  each such partition is a union of orbits. Any one partition may contain two or more orbits.

Comment: Yes, but once you individualize a vertex it becomes the only member of its cell in the partition . It is in an orbit of size 1.

Comment: In the second paragraph you give an counter-example (its not regular), Is there a regular graph which can serve as counter-example here.

Comment: This was a counter-example to "it appears I should choose a vertex with almost the same number of neighbours and non-neighbours." If the graph is regular then number of neighbors and non-neighbors applies equally to all vertices. Maybe you meant number of neighbors and non-neighbors in some cell of the partition?

Comment: Yes I mean the same.